# Get child nodes where parent node has an ID

Tags: javascript, xml

I have tried to make a script that returns the child nodes of an element with a certain ID-attribute, but it fails in every way I do it. Can somone help me?

My XML-document is like this:

```
<prices>
   <car id="1">
      <name>Toyota</name>
      <price_day>250</price_day>
   </car>
   <car id="2">
      <name>Opel</name>
      <price_day>100</price_day>
   </car>
</prices>
```

I want to use `JavaScript` to get only the data on car with `id="1"`. 
My last try was this:

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("car");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
   document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
```

It write all the entries...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var txt='<prices><car id="1"><name>Toyota</name><price_day>250</price_day></car>   <car id="2"><name>Opel</name><price_day>100</price_day></car></prices>';
if (window.DOMParser)
{
  parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
}
else // Internet Explorer
{
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async=false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
} 
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("car");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
    if(x[i].getAttribute('id')=='1')
    {
        alert(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }
}
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/BKazh/2/

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var x= xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("car")[0].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BKazh/4/

Comment: What if the `car id="1"` is on `second index`?